# Not able to run queries using nodeJS using adodb

Tags: sql, node.js, json, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to execute queries onto an .accdb file using node-adodb. i came across an error like this

```
{ Error: Spawn C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript.exe error
at ChildProcess.child.on.exitCode (C:\Users\Sumukh Bharadwaj\Desktop\NodeJS\node_modules\node-adodb\lib\spawn.js:120:37)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)


process:


{ code: -2146824582,
 message: 'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.' },


exitCode: 0 }
```

I'm not able to proceed further from this.
Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a valid Access installation or an installation of the Access Database Engine to use ADO.

Since the error refers to SysWow64, you need to install the 32-bits variant of the Access Database Engine (or Access application).

Comment: Is there any way using a 64bit variant?

Comment: The docs on the extension are not in a language I can understand, but as far as I can understand, `ADODB.open(connection[, x64])` takes two arguments, the second one indicating a 64-bits connection.

Comment: I encountered this problem now, my Acces is 64 bits and I was trying to run a query and got the same issue... Solved it by adding a process.arch condition to the .open method: `ADODB.open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + dbPath + "';", process.arch.includes('64'));`